# Create a wire coil

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, transforms

I want to create this: [image: coil]
Note that wire lay chaotically, so spiral object not the same thing. 
There is a cool way to do this task in 3ds max: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAIrlxPUnqM
Basically he deform straight spline/curve and then bend it couple iterations (over 9000 degrees angle in max). 
[image: how it's done]
Blender can't bend that way with simple deform as I know, only up to 360 degree. Is there any other way to make wire wrapping similar to photo?

Comment: You can go further than 360° with simple deform. But to do so, you need to type in the value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create it easily with a bezier curve spiral.

[image: Coil]

1. Activate the addon *Add Curve Extra Objects* in user preferences
2. Add a new curve spiral with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Curve > Add Curve Spirals: > Archemidian*
3. Adjust the number or turns as desired, about $8$ should suffice
4. Adjust radius growth to a low value, about one tenth of the total radius you set up.
5. Keep vertex count low, you won't need many vertex, curve will take care of the rest.
6. Set the type to *Poly* and adjust everything as desired, but make sure you leave the *Height* parameter at $0$
7. Rotate it in $Z$ so its end vertex are symmetrical, erase one end vertex if necessary so they both start and end at $X=0$
   [image: Spiral Add]
8. In edit mode move the end vertex 1/10 of the total radius down, and the start vertex 1/10th of the total radius up
9. In *Edit Mode* duplicate everything and move it up so the ends connect perfectly. Manually check that they do by moving vertex as necessary.
   [image: End vertex]
10. Now duplicate everything and move up double the previous height several times, enough to make the coil as big as required.

[image: duplicate up]

11. Convert to mesh, so you can quickly remove doubles and the ends connect, then convert back to curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> menu
    [image]
12. In *Edit Mode* set curve type to *Bezier* and handle types to *Automatic*
13. Bevel as desired.
14. Now use *Proportional Edit* set to *Random* fallof type to move or scale vertex around and give it a rougher random appearance as desired.

[image: Proportional edit]

Comment: Excellent work with the animated GIFs! Very elucidating.

Comment: Could you have used the Array modifier to repeat the process? (question, not request)

Comment: Yes, you totally could, but since adding the 'randomness' would most likely require it to be applied afterwards, I decided too just stick to edit mode operations

Comment: Can you plz explain in little detail the 9th point how to connect the duplicate part with the top and below. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

You may achieve it using ***Curve Extra Objects***--> ***Torus Knot Plus***. It's the laziest solution I guess :).
[image]

Enable the ***Curve Extra Objects*** add on in User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Curve*-->*Torus Knot Plus* to add a spiral and play with its settings. Add another one, change its settings (to make it look slightly different from the previous one) and scale it to make the wire look more dense.
[image]

***NOTE:*** You may use the ***proportional editing*** to make the wire look more messy.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it can bend more than 360°, just input with the numpad.

Here's how I would do it (roughly):

1. Create Bezier curve
2. Make it straight
3. Scale it up by 10
4. Subdivide it with 100 cuts
5. Randomize
6. Add a "Simple Deform" modifier
7. Select "Bend"
8. Input 10000 degrees
9. In edit mode, rotate curve by 1.5° along Y axis
10. Set curve to Full
11. Set bevel depth to .005 and resolution to 2
12. Boom.
13. haha !

[image]