# How to give the effect or how to make reference image model

Tags: modeling, mesh, effects

[image] A reference image is attached. I want to make the color thread roll and want that coil effect to the inner cylinder. I dont want to use the texture. i want that thread to be coil and look similar to the reference image. Any idea 
A reference video of 3dmax https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAIrlxPUnqM

Comment: A similiar question with the same tutorial reference has been asked already.http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65188/create-a-wire-coil

Answer (score -1):

It's probebly two way to do it.
The first is to do it by hand and spend hours of modeling.
The second is to try to do a simulation that spins up the thred on to the roll.

You can cheat and use torus(the donut) where it isn't in view.