# How do I create a cable coil?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, transforms

Hey I'm wondering how I would go about creating a cable coil in Blender? I don't even know where to begin.. 
[image]

Comment: [Model a simple 3D spiral shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/model-a-simple-3d-spiral-shape)

Comment: and [Create a wire coil](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65188/create-a-wire-coil)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99660/modelling-a-mechanical-spring-for-a-bike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use screw modifier to get the result. here is a quick demonstration
[image]

add circles like these in a mesh. more circles means more rings. Use smaller circle to get the result as shown in the ref.

[image]

then make sure the origin is in the 3d cursor. Now add a screw modifier and tweak the settings as shown. Use the iterations value to increase the length of the wires.

Comment: This is a good start but make sure to understand how a cable coil works, as the winding is a bit different than here and it is one single cable. Also it might not be necessary to create all layers but only the outer one